# Will I be still getting segwit2x coins if I store BTC in my desktop BTC wallet

Tags: segwit2x

I'm with three exchanges, one says they don't support BTG and therefore user should withdraw their BTC before Nov 16th's fork takes place.

Another one says they will issue 1:1 segwit2x.

The last one doesn't seem giving a clear answer.

I have some BTC in these three places. If I withdraw my BTC to my desktop wallet, would I be able to receive segwit2x and BTG when fork take place?

Comment: Segwit2x was cancelled (see https://medium.com/@OneMorePeter/onwards-all-in-on-segwit-9e7cb3faa73d), so this question is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some BTC in these three places. If I withdraw my BTC to my desktop wallet, would I be able to receive segwit2x and BTG when fork take place?

Nope, BTG hard fork has already happened. If your exchanges don't support BTG, then there is nothing you can do to claim your BTG.

You can still withdraw your BTC if you want to claim your S2X coins, and if you do, you'll be able to claim them after the hard fork. (~15th of November)

Comment: How exactly do I claim them after the hard fork?

Comment: @lsd just wait for "Electrum Gold" or something like that (a bitcoin wallet). It may take a month. Also don't fall for scams, 100% of "claim your bitcoin gold" websites are scam. The only official website is https://bitcoingold.org/. Keep an eye on that website.

Comment: @Isd comment ^^

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. So if I send all my BTC from three exchanges to my own wallet I will be able to receive S2X coins right? 

How long do I need to keep the coins in my BTC wallet for it to qualify?

Comment: are you saying that if a wallet such as "Electrum Gold" comes out, I will still be able to claim bitcoin gold by sending my btc coins to such wallet?

Comment: @lsd You'll need your private keys.

Answer (score 0):

It technically doesn't matter where you store your BTC, if you had BTC when the fork happened then you can claim your altcoins via various methods but, you will need your private keys for the wallet where the BTC was kept on that date (or your recovery passphrase) to import into a supporting wallet.